# Write a function filter_long_words() that takes a list of words and an integer n and returns the list of words that are longer than n

Tags: python

Whenever I run this code it just gives me a blank list, I am wondering what I am doing wrong. I am trying to print a list of words that are longer than n. When i try to run the updated code it only prints the first word from the list of words that i enter.

```
def filterlongword(string,number):

    for i in range(len(string)):
        listwords = []
        if len(string[i]) > number:
            listwords.append(string[i])

        return listwords 


def main():
    words = input("Please input the list of words: ")
    integer = eval(input("Please input an integer: "))

    words1 = filterlongword(words,integer)

    print("The list of words greater than the integer is",words1)

main()
```

Comment: You're returning too soon, unindent the return statement.

Answer (score 1):

- Initialize `listwords` *before* the loop
- Return `listwords` *after* the loop
- Split the input string into a list of words

```
def filterlongword(string,number):
    listwords = []
    for i in range(len(string)):
        if len(string[i]) > number:
            listwords.append(string[i])
    return listwords
```

And a nicer version using [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
def filterlongword(string,number):
    return [word for word in string if len(word) > number]
```

To split the input string into a list of words, use

```
words = input("Please input the list of words: ").split()
```

Answer (score 0):

even better would be just

```
def filterlongword(string,number):
    return filter(lambda word:len(word)>number, string)
    # or: return [w for w in string if len(w) > number]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def listing(guess, number):

    new_list = []

    for i in range(len(guess)):
        if len(guess[i]) > number:
            new_list.append(guess[i])

    print (new_list)

list1 = input("take input: ")

list = list1.split(",")

def main():
    global list, integer1
    integer = input()
    integer1 = int(integer)
    listing(list, integer1)

main()
```

**try this code..this will work, use a delimiter to form a list of your input **

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is passing words as a single string rather than an iterable of strings.  The secondary problem is not specifying the separator between words for the missing .split.  Here is my version.

I made `longwords` a generator function because in actually use, one does not necessary need the sequence of long words to be a list, and I gave an example of this in the output formatting.

```
def longwords(wordlist, length):
    return (word for word in wordlist if len(word) >= length)

def main():
    words = input("Enter words, separated by spaces: ").split()
    length = int(input("Minimum length of words to keep: "))
    print("Words longer than {} are {}.".format(length,
          ', '.join(longwords(words, length))))

main()
```

This results in, for instance

```
Enter words, separated by spaces: a bb ccc dd eeee f ggggg
Minimum length of words to keep: 3
Words longer than 3 are ccc, eeee, ggggg.
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can shorten the code to the following:

```
def filter_long_words():
    n = raw_input("Give words and a number: ").split() 
    return sorted(n)[1:] # sorted the List , number it is the shorter .
                     # called the item from the second position to ende .
print filter_long_words()
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def filter_long_words(**words**,**number**):
    l=[]
    split = **words**.split(",") 

    for i in split:
        if len(i) > **number**:
            l.append(i)
    return l


**w** = input("enter word:")

**n** = int(input("Enter number"))

filter_long_words(**w**,**n**)
```

Comment: Please add some explanations when you answer a question.

Answer (score 0):

---

> TRY THIS

```
*** 

def filter_long_words(n, words):
    list_of_words=[]
    a= words.split(" ")
    for x in a:
      if len(x)>n:
        list_of_words.append(x)
    return list_of_words
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(len(listOfWords)):
listOfInt = []

for i in range(len(listOfWords)):
    listOfInt.append(len(listOfWords[i]))

print('List of word length: ',listOfInt)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes

Answer (score 0):

```py
def filter_long_words(lst,n):
    a=[]
    for i in lst:
        if n<len(i):
            a.append(i)
    return a
```

Comment: Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better.

Answer (score -1):

To filter list of words

```
def filter_long_words(lst,n):
    
    return [word for word in lst if len(word)>n]
```